# Misaligned columns in rstudio when viewing dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, r-sf

When viewing dataframes in the "Source" section of RStudio, the columns are frequently misaligned, making it difficult to read.

I'm not sure what is causing this, and playing around with the width of the columns doesn't seem to help. I've looked at the "known issue" of column misalignment, but as far as I could tell, it seemed to be a different error. I'm not sure if this is due to something in my settings, but nothing there seems to apply, and restarting RStudio doesn't do anything either.

This happens when clicking on the object in the `Data` section of the environment, which prints:

`View(cps_tiers`

At this point, the dataframe loads fine, but the columns are hard to read. Here is an image of what I'm describing:
[image]

Comment: To control the structure of your Dataframe use `str(cps_tiers)`

Comment: I think this is an Rstudio issue, check your version and update/revert to stable if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calum You was correct, I updated RStudio and the issue seems to have gone away. Thanks for the help!